# How to close a RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to close a RandomAccessFile but resource remain busy.

Code:

```
public boolean isOpen(RandomAccessFile f) {
        try {
            f.length() ;
            return true ;
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return false ;
        }
    }
```

---

```
this.rfmFile = new File(filePath);
try {
this.rfmRandomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(rfmFile, "rws");
} catch(Exception e){
}finally{
this.rfmRandomAccessFile.close();
}
while(!isOpen(this.rfmRandomAccessFile));
log.debug("I Finally Closed this RAF");
```

Log is not showed and thread goes in loop.
When I try to access to my resource from shell it gives me "Device or Resource busy".

The only way to access is kill java process.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the ';' after your while statement could imply an endless loop.

Comment: Try  getting the stack trace in both your `catch` statements instead of suppressing the `Exception` / ` IOException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to access the RandomAccessFile length(), method, it is already closed and thus you cannot access it anymore.
You probably want to use the length() method of File. Your loop cannot work as the RandomAccessFile was already closed.
But I must admit I am clueless on the low level reason why rfmRandomAccessFile would not really be closed. It could be a side effect of your strange loop trying to get the size of a closed file.

[edit:]Could not reproduce your issue with the following piece of code:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        File file = new File("foobar.txt");
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = null;
        try {
            randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rws");
            randomAccessFile.write(new byte[]{'f'});
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(randomAccessFile !=null){
                try {
                    randomAccessFile.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //doh!
                }
            }
        }
        FileReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new FileReader(file);
            char read = (char) reader.read();
            System.out.println("what was written: "+read);
            System.out.println("file size: "+file.length());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(reader !=null){
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //doh!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an example roughly simulating your case, and well, it works like it should.

Comment: no way, my file is  a resource ( /dev/rfm12b.0.1). 
When i try to send a shell command while java is running it give me busy error. I closed RAF, try to execute shell command and it give me busy error again.
The only way is to kill java application to be able to use the resource.

Comment: I was even able to delete the file, or fill it with "foobar" while running my piece of code in debug mode and stopping it right after the "randomAccessFile.close();". I cannot see your issue at all.

Comment: The problem isn't the loop, is the device busy. I need to use the resource of the RAF via linux shell after the close and when i try to do it linux give me "Device or Resource busy"

It was a concurrency problem